# Help translating "她只觉得眼前一花，就里看到一个一身锦衣的男子"

Tags: translation, usage, meaning-in-context

"她只觉得眼前一花，就里看到一个一身锦衣的男子"

She only saw patterns in front of her, and then she finally saw a man with brocade clothing.

Is it the correct translation?

I'm confused as why "觉得" is used instead of "看到". I am also confused about "一花" and "就里".

Comment: 现代汉语词典：(  **眼花**  ：看东西模糊不清：头昏～。)  **花**  （３）（～儿）形状像花朵的东西：灯～儿｜火～｜雪～儿。 **就里**  ：内部情况：不知～，bkrs：1) 个中；内中。
2) 内情；底细。inside story， another suggestion： a flash before her eyes, (the reason) she saw ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

花 also means 'burr'

眼花 means 'have blurred vision'

她只觉得眼前**一花** - She just felt **a burr** in front of her eyes

就看到一个一身锦衣的男子 - then she saw a man in brocade clothing

*里 is a typo, it shouldn't be there*

> *I'm confused as why "觉得" is used instead of "看到".*

We say "she 'felt' a burr in front of her eyes" instead of "she 'saw' a burr in front of her eyes" because using '看到 (saw)' in this sentence would mean she has **actually seen** something.

Using 'felt' a burr' in this sentence implies she may or may not had actually seen something. It could just be something wrong with her vision.(for example, she might has fainted a little or  her eyes were watering for a moment)

> The correct translation of "**她只觉得眼前一花，就看到一个一身锦衣的男子**" is 
>   "**She just felt a burr in front of her eyes, then** (she) **saw a man in brocade clothing**"

Comment: This is a strange sentence,  maybe 里 is not a typo, 就里 means 'from there(blurred vision)'',  只觉得....只, or 只觉得...然后就 is more fluent